# Apache Flink: When will the last-watermark (by `Long.MaxValue` value)be triggered? And How should it be handled?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to know exactly

- When will watermark value be set as `Long.MaxValue`? (On canceling a SourceFunction? Cancel a job through cli & web-panel? ... )
- What does it means for an application? (End of the job? Job failure? with no re/start?)
- And how should it be handled? (clearing all the states? what about timers? As I saw registering a new timer on this state will make application to run forever! If I should be able to persist a state in last-watermark to recover from it in later time/run, how I should persist a timer-state?)

Answer (score 0):

The last watermark is emitted when your `SourceFunction` exits the `run` method and it means you have consumed all input.

Given this you should not need to clear as the job will be marked as finished once the watermark reaches all sinks.

Comment: So what about when I cancel my job through web-panel?